# How to replace a version number with sed?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, command-line-interface

```
  <package id="Antlr3.Runtime" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="MathNet.Numerics" version="4.12.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="NCalcAsync" version="3.1.8" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="OdicoGeometryOps" version="1.0.0-20221118-143402" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="VSDaVinci" version="1.0.0-20221118-143815" targetFramework="net471" />
```

I have a package file like this and I would like to update my version for line #5 and line #7 using sed.
Another thing worth mentioning is that the version number for line #5 and line #7 is not static so at any given point it may change.
How can I do this?

Edit:
My req may not be very clear so I'm adding a couple more points. All i want to do is to change the version number on line #5 and line #7. The
version number that i will be changing to and the one im changing is dynamic and i will get it as an argument to a file which i will be using to update it.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Do you want to change the version numbers based on the line numbers or maybe based on the `id`? How do you want to specify the new version numbers? Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: Added some comments

Comment: Do I understand correct that you always want to change lines 5 and 7 and don't want to change tha lines based on their `id` value? So assuming another package of a name starting with `A` will be inserted, then the script is supposed to modify lines 5 and 7 with now different `id`s? What exactly do you mean with "argument to a file which i will be using to update it"? Please add an example how you imagine to run the script?

Comment: You almost certainly do *not* want to change the version on line 5.  You want to change the version on `OdicoGeometryOps`.  Changing the version based on line number is extremely fragile.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#file name
File=demo.txt

##get 2 arguments 
lb1=$1
lb2=$2

sed -i "/^[[:space:]]*[^#]*keyword/c replaceable line" $File
sed -i "/^[[:space:]]*[^#]*keyword/c replaceable line" $File
```

the above script searches for the keyword and replaces the entire line with the replaceable line
Note: it also ignores commented entries in the text file